# JQuery datatable callback called on row deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the latest version of the jQuery datatables. Is there a callback function that called when row is deleted?

I have dynamic table where data can be reloaded and changed during page life. 
I need to ensure that ID column contains unique values and for this I'm concatenating instance number to the IDs, doing this in rowCreated callback.

I'm holding object that contains already existing IDs,  adding new ID in createdRow callback and looking for way to remove already deleted IDs.

my createdRow code:

```
"createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
        if (!data || data.length == 0) return;

        var id;

        if(firstRender ||
           data[INDEX_ID].toString().indexOf('.') == -1) {
                id = (data[INDEX_ID]).toString();
                id = generateKey(id, ID_MAP);
                data[INDEX_ID] = id;
                ID_MAP[id] = row;
            }          
    }
```

want to add something like:

```
"destroyedRow"(row, data){
        ID_MAP.remove(data[INDEX_ID]);
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [fnDeleteRow()](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDeleteRow) function and then remove the index, as:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable(),
    rowID = 1;
oTable.fnDeleteRow( rowID );
//remove ID from your array
```

Comment: Table support few ways to remove rows (such as removing specific row, loading new data to table (overriding previous), getting update and etc.). I prefer to catch row deleting event and handle it once than duplicating code to all these scenarios.